# Is it secure to put password in POST request?

Tags: java, security, rest

I developing web services,

these services are `rest` services and are used by mobile application.

for example, if the user wants to log in, he/she has to call this link

`mySever:myPort/login`

and in the post of the request, they use their passwords and usernames.

is this way secure?

#### note that i change the password to sha256 before calling the web service

if this way not secure, can u suggest other options please?

Comment: Well most of the login forms are doing it. The process as such isn't unsecure, but if anybody is sniffing the network (which is obviously easy when on a public wi-fi hotspot) and you post your data without encryption (SSL), this can be revealed, as other thing like cookies (including session cookies) that can be as harmful as having the password... so the key is to use SSL, not to hash the password...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if you do all the communications over SSL.

Comment: Dear Mr. Tim, do you mean https?

Comment: unfortunately, it is not on https, can u suggest other options to secure my server please?

Comment: @user3110137: You **need** to use HTTPS.  Security is hard; if you try to make your own version of SSL, you will fail.  In particular, you _must_ validate the server certificate.

Comment: For your initial testing and such like you don't need to pay any money out - use a self signed certificate for that and you only need to buy one when the site is ready.

Comment: @TimB if i have to use ssl, so i should use public and private key, are these key can get by money? or i can use my own keys?

Comment: @user3110137: If you use your own key, you will have no way to revoke it from existing clients if it gets compromised.

Comment: You can use your own key DURING DEVELOPMENT ONLY. Once you are ready to deploy you will need to buy a key from a Certificate Authority. They don't need to be expensive, shop around and you can get very bsaic SSL certificates for not much money at all.

Comment: @SLaks please, is the changes large in code when added the ssl, or not?

Comment: That depends on your HTTP framework.  Make sure that it verifies the remote certificate.

Comment: No, it's server level configuration (i.e. tomcat, glassfish, etc) for the most part. But you need to go away and read up on all of this, we can't feed you all the answers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_SSL

Answer (score 2):

## Use HTTPS!

If you use HTTP and make sure to validate the server certificate, you will be reasonably secure.

If you make your own authentication protocol, you are very likely to create vulnerabilities.

If you just send a hash of the password, you haven't added any security; the attacker can replay the same hash.

Comment: so can i use my own public and private key, which i can generate from VS, or it is imporatant to buy them from a trusted site ?

Comment: @user3110137: If you generate your own keypair, you can embed the public key directly in the client app instead of using PKI.  However, if someone steals the key, you will have no way to revoke it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using SSL, you should use some means to avoid replay attacks. If you just hash the password by itself, someone could very easily capture the hash and send it themselves. One way to do this would be to use a nonce that you send to the user, and that they add to the password before hashing. This nonce should be unique (you could use a timestamp for example).

So instead of hash(password) you would do hash(password+nonce). Then you would compare, since you both hold the password and the nonce.